# I can't seem to get my static files to load using Django

Tags: css, django, static, django-staticfiles

I can't seem for the life of me to get my static files to work... I've been reading documentation here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#static-root

And I've come to the conclusion that I need the following settings

```
STATIC_ROOT
STATIC_URL
STATICFILES_DIR
```

I believe `STATIC_ROOT` is if I want to use `./manage.py collectstatic` and have them all in one folder for deployment, so I don't need that

Currently my STATIC_URL is

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**And I'm not sure what my `STATICFILES_DIRS` should be set to. I've literally tried every single combination I can think of.**

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    "E:\PyProjects\elsablog\static"
)
```

I currently have it hardcoded and it still doesn't work!

```
 elsablog
      blog
           static
                blog
      elsablog
      static***
```

I'd like to put the files into the static*** folder that not the static folder in my blog app. (My bootstrap, js, css, so I want to be able to access it globally)

Here is my index.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<SCRIPT SRC=/static/js/test.js"% ></SCRIPT>
<ul>
{% for topic in topic_list %}

    <li>{{ topic.topic_text}}</li>
    <ul>

    {% for subtopic in subtopic_list %}
        {% if subtopic.topic.topic_text == topic.topic_text%}
            <li>{{ subtopic.subtopic_text}}</a></li>
        {% endif %}

        <ul>
        {% for question in question_list %}
            {% if question.topic.topic_text == topic.topic_text and question.subtopic.subtopic_text == subtopic.subtopic_text%}
                <li><a href="/blog/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endfor %}
</ul>

<A HREF="javascript:a_message()">Click for eea message..</A>

{% endblock content %}
```

and my base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% load staticfiles %}

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Esla's Blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/prism.css" %}">
    <script src="{% static "js/prism.js" %}"></script>
    <SCRIPT SRC=/static/js/test.js"% ></SCRIPT>

</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}


<A HREF="javascript:a_message()">Click for a message..</A>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd really appreciate some help, Thanks guys~!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From django docs re: STATICFILES_DIRS:

> This setting defines the additional locations the staticfiles app will
>   traverse if the FileSystemFinder finder is enabled, e.g. if you use
>   the collectstatic or findstatic management command or use the static
>   file serving view.
>
> The default will find files stored in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting
>   (using django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder) and in a
>   static subdirectory of each app (using
>   django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder).

Either way, try this one in your settings file instead of your current setting:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
)
```

Comment: That didn't work! =( The weird thing is... In my console I see this

`[16/Aug/2015 11:51:35]"GET /static/css/prism.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1652

[16/Aug/2015 11:51:35]"GET /static/js/prism.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1646

[16/Aug/2015 11:51:35]"GET /static/js/test.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1643`

Comment: OK, let's try to fix it. Does anything change with a DEBUG = True setting ?

Comment: I've been running it with debug set to true.

Comment: Woah, I don't know what happened but I reran the server and it worked with your code!! THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

You should run this command

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

For more details on how to serve static content read [django docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/).